# I am trying to add image to tab bar item but is not loading

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-navigation, jsx

**I want to add image to tab bar icon and want to change tab bar background color**

referring https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1205#issuecomment-296708338

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import ScreenOne from './ScreenOne';
import Screentwo from './Screentwo';
import Preferences from './Preferences';



const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
  Home: ScreenOne,
  Settings: Screentwo,
  Preference: Preferences
},
{  
  initialRouteName: "Home",
  showLabel: false,
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'blue',
    inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'darkcerulean'
    },
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 13
    }
  },
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor, image }) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state;
      let imagepath;

      if (routeName === "Home") {
        imagepath = "require('../images/Help_Header_Icon.png')";
      } else if (routeName === "Settings") {
        imagepath = "require('../images/Settings.png')";
      } else if (routeName === "Preference") {
        imagepath = "require('../images/Preference.png')";
      }
      return (
        <Image
          style={{ width: 30, height: 30, resizeMode: "stretch" }}
          source={imagepath}
        />
      );
    }
  }
  )
}
);


export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

> I want to add image to tab bar icon and want to change tab bar
>   background color

Comment: "require('../images/Help_Header_Icon.png')" - try use it without "..."

Comment: I removed " " then also not working

Comment: now, check your pathes (for example you can move imagepath = require('../images/Help_Header_Icon.png' to head of file, and show it in console.log)

Comment: paths are correct this code is running perfectly nut after app launch icon not loading

Comment: I got the icon now as I change image with different color it was happening because of bar color and image both are white, how can I change color of bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load your requires previously like this

```
const images = {
  imagepathA: require('../images/Help_Header_Icon.png'),
  imagepathB: require('../images/Settings.png'),
  imagepathC: require('../images/Preference.png'),
};
```

and in your return use it like this

```
 if (routeName === "Home") {
    imagepath = images.imagepathA;
  } else if (routeName === "Settings") {
    imagepath = images.imagepathB;
  } else if (routeName === "Preference") {
    imagepath = images.imagepathC;
  }
  return (
        <Image
          style={{ width: 30, height: 30, resizeMode: "stretch" }}
          source={imagepath}
        />
      );
```